# Best way to get a unique hardware address in Windows and save it to a text file?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch

I’m working on a project that requires a script to run on Windows 7 and 10 start up that will save any unique hardware address of a workstation (the workstation has 2 Dell monitors and a HP dock) to a text file.

Originally I had it so a batch script would run and save the MAC address of the dock to a text file. However I have recently found out that the newer laptops running Windows 10 have MAC address pass through enabled hence the MAC address saved is not unique to the workstation only the laptop itself.

Any idea on a way to get a unique address of hardware in a workstation? I was thinking maybe a PowerShell script to get the serial number of the monitor or does anybody know of a way to access the docks original MAC address before it was overridden?

Comment: MAC addresses are not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: You can get a lot of hardware information through WMI including serial numbers of some hardware.